# I need help understanding mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I am using `cloud 9` and I successfully installed mongo and mongoose.
The terminal says: err

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

I looked at the cloud 9 mongo docs but I was unable to find the solution. At first I thought I had to install this under the same directory as my app but I was incorrect.

How do I solve this problem. I also tried to connect to the database by using

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/profile_app");
```

Comment: did you check folder `node_modules` in your app folder is there mongoose ?

Comment: In node_modules I do not see the mongoose folder how would I include it?

Comment: did you install mongoose like this doc https://docs.c9.io/docs/installing-npm-modules ?

Comment: I did not use npm to install mongo I followed this website https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-mongodb

Comment: then you need to install `mongoose` that's the driver used by nodejs to connect to mongodb, this doc https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-mongodb only show you how to setup mongo

Comment: Cool thank you for your help I got it. I just had to run npm install --save mongoose and that fixed my problems thank you very much. This help came from -Nicolas McCurdy and -somallg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The require function only works with modules included in your `node_modules` directory. The proper way to add dependencies is to add them to `package.json` and run `npm install`.

A shortcut to install a specific dependency is `npm install --save mongoose`, which will both install the module and add it to `package.json`. If you do not have a `package.json` file, run `npm init` first to create one.